# How can I debug NSManagedObjects in XCode debugger?

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging, nsmanagedobject

How do you get to the values of your Entity (sub class of NSManaged Object) when in the XCode debugger?  I get lost among the NSObject and _cd_XXX structures.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you select the entity in the variables pane and then choose "Print Description to Console" from the contextual menu, you get a textual dump of the entity.

Comment: not exactly what I was looking for but you got 6 votes and it works as described.

Answer (score 10):

In the Debugger Console type

```
po [your_entity your_property]
```

I don't really know another useful way, as the entity may e.g. be faulted and also the NSManagedObject structure isn't really helpful, as you already noticed.

Answer (score 1):

Go into the debugger window, right-click, "Add Expression..." and type in the expression as it would appear in the code; you can also type `p <expression>` in the debugger to similar effect. For example in my case:

```
managedObjectContext.registeredObjects.first?.value(forKey: "shifts") as? [Shift]
```

If you're dealing with something which is an undifferentiated `NSObject` or `NSManagedObject` or similar then this can be a bit of a pain and you may want to dump the expression as described in the other answers here, but if the object does have a proper interface (e.g., the variable has a type of `NSObject` but the object has a more specific class) then casting it in the debugger would generally do nicely.